# Is every Jordan block diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

> Is every Jordan block diagonalisable?

I need to also give a short justification. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Well, what do you think about the problem?

Answer (score 5):

if every Jordan block would be diagonalizable, then every matrix would be diagonalizable, and then nobody would care about Jordan blocks.

Pick the smallest possible non-trivial Jordan block and try to diagonalize it. Just a tiny amount of work would had solved the problem for you.

Comment: This approach only helps someone that understands what it means diagonalize a matrix, and why we care about Jordan blocks. This answer does nothing to address OP's deep and apparent lack of understanding.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's why i suggested in the second part actually picking a small Jordan block and try to diagonalize it...

Comment: *Every matrix whose characteristic polynomial splits would be diagonalizable?

Comment: @JonathanHebert If one wants to be precise, yes you are right :)

Comment: Another way to put it is "over which field will it split"? A matrix is always diagonalizable, the question is just, "how complicated do we need to make the field" or "how complicated eigenvalues do we permit"?

Comment: @mathreadler Are you sure? As far as I know $\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is never diagonalizable.(unless $0=1$),

Comment: @N.S. Yes, unless it becomes useful to consider it an element in it's own right. It does such an important job transforming multiplication into addition so I think in some contexts it might deserve to.